# Open/Run Macro/Save & Close

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate the execution of a macro once on all files in a folder, using this code:

```
Sub LoopFile()
Dim fso as Object  'Scritping.FileSystemObject
Dim fldr as Object 'Scripting.Folder
Dim file as Object 'Scripting.File
Dim wb as Workbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\DataBanks001\TEST\")

For Each file In fldr.Files
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
    Call ListWorkSheetAndUpdate

    wb.Close (True)
Next

Set file = Nothing
Set fldr = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

The problem is that once all files have been processed it loops back to the beginning and starts again - basically running the same macro on each workbook more than once; a patchwork solution was to use this other code:

```
Sub AllFiles()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook

folderPath = "C:\DataBanks001\TEST\" 

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls")
Do While filename <> ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)

    Call ListWorkSheetAndUpdate

    filename = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

which does not close&save, but processes the workbooks only once - however leaving them opened causes excel to crash after their cumulative size gets too big.
Is there a way to stop the code after the last file in a folder has been processed?

Since my macro creates a new summary sheet in the workbooks, I was thinking a possible workaround was to count the sheets in each opened workbook, and if the number were to be >(n+1) stop the sub. Could this be a possible solution?

@findwindow - The code is the following less some formulas:

```
Sub ListWorkSheetAndUpdate()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets.Add.Name = "Master"

xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Application.Sheets(xTitleId).Delete
Application.Sheets.Add Application.Sheets(1)
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
xWs.Name = xTitleId
For I = 2 To Application.Sheets.Count
    xWs.Range("A" & (I - 1)) = Application.Sheets(I).Name
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Worksheets("Master").Range("A1").Value = "Sheet"
Worksheets("Master").Range("B1").Value = "SAE"
Worksheets("Master").Range("C1").Value = "CODE"
Worksheets("Master").Range("D1").Value = "COD_TRX"
Worksheets("Master").Range("E1").Value = "Add Index"
Worksheets("Master").Range("F1").Value = "Add Match"
Worksheets("Master").Range("G1").Value = "Add SIC"
Worksheets("Master").Range("H1").Value = "GRID"   
Worksheets("Master").Range("J1").Value = "VART"
Worksheets("Master").Range("K1").Value = "OP.R"

Worksheets("Master").Range("A2:A101").Formula = "=KutoolsforExcel!RC"
Worksheets("Master").Range("B2:B101").Formula = "=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(RC[-1],""!A1""))"
Worksheets("Master").Range("C2:C101").Formula = "=RIGHT(LEFT(RC[9],LEN(RC[9])-14),5)"
Worksheets("Master").Range("D2:D101").Formula = "=RIGHT(LEFT(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14),LEN(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14))-5),LEN(LEFT(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14),LEN(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14))-5))-(FIND(""~"",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14),LEN(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14))-5),"","",""~"",(LEN(LEFT(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14),LEN(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14))-5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14),LEN(LEFT(RC[8],LEN(RC[8])-14))-5),"","",""""))))))-1)"
Worksheets("Master").Range("E2:E101").Value = "!A:D"
Worksheets("Master").Range("F2:F101").Value = "!C:C"
Worksheets("Master").Range("G2:G101").Value = "!A:A"
Worksheets("Master").Range("H2:H101").Formula = "=INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(RC[-7],RC[-3])),MATCH(R1C8,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(RC[-7],RC[-2])),0),4)"   
Worksheets("Master").Range("J2:J101").Formula = "=INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(RC[-9],RC[-5])),MATCH(R1C10,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(RC[-9],RC[-3])),0),2)"
Worksheets("Master").Range("K2:K101").Formula = "=INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(RC[-10],RC[-6])),MATCH(R1C11,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(RC[-10],RC[-4])),0),2)"


Worksheets("Master").Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Worksheets("Master").Columns("L:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Sheets("KutoolsforExcel").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I find the simplest solution to be: Move the file out of the directory once you've processed it.  That way the only files in there are the unprocessed ones and when there are none left...

Comment: For the second code block, why not just add `wb.close true` after `Call ListWorkSheetAndUpdate`?

Comment: @Dave Yes, it would be the simplest solution, but i cannot move the files (are shared); saving the processed files somewhere else won't solve it either, as the code would keep "fishing" xls from the folder I selected.

Comment: @findwindow If I add the close&save statement to the second code block it acts like the first one - looping ad infinitum

Comment: Then `ListWorkSheetAndUpdate` is doing something funky because I use the same code and have no problem.

Comment: Beats me :/ As an side, consider using `with`.

Comment: Should be able to shorten to `Worksheets("Master").Columns("A:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit` as well, instead of a line for every column.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I dealt with a situation where I'm looping through files in a directory, I create a separate worksheet for a log of file paths that have already been iterated through. You can then program your script to only process files that are not yet in the index. It's extra processing, but an easy solution. Once all the files are present in the log, you can wrap up execution.